# Convergence of an infinite series with doublefactorials.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ s(n) = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\left(-1 \right)^{\lfloor 1 /2\,k \rfloor }
\frac{\left(n\pi \right)^{k}}{\left(2\,k \right)!! } $$

Show that $s(n)$ is an integer for all $n \ge 0$. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hint of Robert Israel we see that $s(x)$ is the Maclaurin expansion of $\cos(x\pi/2)+\sin(x\pi/2)$ which is valid everywhere. Thus $s(n) = 1,1,-1,-1,1,1,\ldots$ for integer $n \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: compare to the Maclaurin series for $\sin$ and $\cos$.